# How do I make the operator work in the equation to make ans?

Tags: python, math, random

[Image of current code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdN57.png)

Currently if I test by printing 'ans', it just prints it as a character like '+' which doesn't work with the equation for 'ans', how do I change this so it adds?
[what 'ans' prints as](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSovk.png)

I'm very new to coding so this may seem like an obvious question- sorry!

Comment: You need to improve your way in thinking and and problem solving.  It is very easy to do that thing you can use a dictionary.

Comment: please [copy and paste code as text into question instead of images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: another request not to post text/code as images!  images are more difficult for everybody as they have to retype your code themselves (potentially introducing unintentional errors), visually impaired users have an even harder time as screen-readers generally can't do anything with an image beyond saying it exists

Answer (score 2):

the right answer for your case is probably to use branching if else

```
ans = (5,'+',6)
if ans[1] == '+':
   print(ans[0] + ans[2])
elif ans[1] == "/":
   print(ans[0] / ans[2]) 
# etc.
```

you could possibly get away with ast.literal_eval

```
import ast
ans = (6,'-',2)
eqn = f"{ans[0]} {ans[1]} {ans[2]}"
print("EQN:",eqn,"=",ast.literal_eval(eqn))
```

the most correct answer however is probably to use a dictionary mapping
to deliberately expose specific programmer defined operators

```
import operator
# the function to call for a given operator
operators = {"+":operator.add,
             '-':operator.sub}
ans = (6,'-',2)
operators[ans[1]](ans[0],ans[2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Change definition of ans to :

```
ans = eval(str(n1) + ops + str(n2))
```

> This makes a string of operands and operator stitched together. And
> then calls eval() function in python which evaluates arithmetic
> operations denoted by string.

Comment: should use `ast.literal_eval` generally `eval` is not a good recommendation and can lead to very serious problems later (of coarse there are exceptions... and this will work)

Comment: The current use case is simple and wont have exceptions, so eval() is the easiest choice.

Comment: ... this is a simple case where `ast.literal_eval` might be appropriate ... its not worth saving a few characters to `eval` user inputted code ... really unless you absolutely know exactly what you are doing you should NEVER use eval ...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this :

```py
def sum(num1,num2):
    print(int(num1)+int(num2))



operations = {"+":sum}

operator = input("Enter :").split()

operations.get(operator[1])(operator[0],operator[2])
```

There are many ways to do it or to solve your problem.